How to access OpenVPN client LAN from Synology RT2600AC as OpenVPN server?
I have a remote router (not Synology) connecting to my local Synology RT2600ac router as an OpenVPN client and would like to access the devices behind it from the local network. The necessary route directive to the openvpn.conf file gets removed after a service restart or device reboot.
While it would be easier to set the remote router as the OpenVPN server, it's using LTE for the WAN connection and is assigned a CGNAT IP so inbound connections are not possible. Getting a static IP is not feasible (it's a consumer-grade account).
How do I get the route settings to stick?

First, it turns out that while Synology markets the RT2600ac as offering OpenVPN in a server configuration, Synology's implementation has limited capabilities (e.g. supports only tun mode, no tap, and requires the deprecated net30 topology) due to their config UI and back-end scripts. The specific OpenVPN version (2.4.11) is also considered end-of-life and unsupported according to this OpenVPN wiki.
That said, I have found a way to keep route directives in the openvpn.conf file through restarts and reboots. NOTE THAT THIS IS UNSUPPORTED BY SYNOLOGY TECHNICAL SUPPORT AND YOUR CHANGES MAY GET REMOVED WHEN UPDATING SRM OR THE VPN PLUS SERVER PACKAGE.
The following changes need to be made via SSH console using an account with administrator privileges (e.g. able to run sudo).
Key Elements:

/var/packages/VPNPlusServer/target/scripts/openvpn.sh
/var/packages/VPNPlusServer/target/scripts/restart_openvpn.sh
/usr/syno/etc/packages/VPNPlusServer/openvpn/openvpn.conf
The LAN IP and Subnet Mask of the client network. In my case 10.168.0.0/16 and 10.128.0.0/16 are LANs of two distinct clients.

Procedure

Edit /var/packages/VPNPlusServer/target/scripts/openvpn.sh and /var/packages/VPNPlusServer/target/scripts/restart_openvpn.sh

Inside the modify_push_route () procedure, the fourth line searches for routes in preparation for removal. The line should look like either of these:
/bin/grep route "${CONF_DIR}/${OPENVPN_CONF}" | /bin/grep -v "${ServerInfo}" | while read -r line
/bin/grep route "${OPENVPN_CONFIG}" | /bin/grep -v "${ServerInfo}" | while read -r line

Modify the grep search string from route to ^route. This will force the script to ignore route directives preceded by a space or double-dash (--). The modified lines should look like one of these:
/bin/grep ^route "${CONF_DIR}/${OPENVPN_CONF}" | /bin/grep -v "${ServerInfo}" | while read -r line
/bin/grep ^route "${OPENVPN_CONFIG}" | /bin/grep -v "${ServerInfo}" | while read -r line

Edit /usr/syno/etc/packages/VPNPlusServer/openvpn/openvpn.conf and add your route directive preceding it with either a space or double-dash. I added mine just below the server directive, between two comment lines. Save the changes.
server 10.0.160.0 255.255.255.0
##inject start
--route 10.168.0.0 255.255.0.0
 route 10.128.0.0 255.255.0.0
##inject end


[RECOMMENDED BUT OPTIONAL] Save the additional route values in a backup file in case they are removed. I created openvpn.inject

Reboot the router by executing reboot or restart OpenVPN by executing openvpn restart


NOTE: For routing to the client-side LAN to work you must also include the iroute directive (e.g. iroute 10.128.0.0 255.255.0.0) in a client instance config file using --client-config-dir (aka. ccd). See the --iroute directive in the Reference Manual for more information.
Why it works
The OpenVPN 2.4 Reference Manual: Options states that configuration options may be included in a config file and that the double-leading-dash ("--") may be omitted. As a result, it appears leading spaces and double-dashes do not interfere with the directives being applied at run-time. Additionally, these lines are ignored by the startup scripts because of the changes in step three.
